# What is the "IsolatedCommand" registry value? What purpose does it serve?

Tags: windows-registry

I have been searching for explanation for this undocumented registry key but all I could find was some reference to taking ownership or running as Administrator, without really explaining what that particular registry value (not key) is designed for.

I also found this link that suggests that:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.exe\
>   shell\open\command | IsolatedCommand =
>   ""%1? %*"

is related to spyware. Is this true? If so, how?

Any idea what this "IsolatedCommand" value is about, and why would Microsoft create a registry value that would help spyware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is apparently a symptom of the [Win32/FakeRean](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mmpc/archive/2010/03/09/win32-fakerean-is-33-rogues-in-1.aspxBlockquote). Briefly,

> Win32/FakeRean is a family of programs that claim to scan for malware and display fake warnings of malicious files. They then inform the user that they need to pay money to register the software in order to remove these non-existent threats.

When Windows is trying to determine what to do with files of any given type, it generally consults the `HKLM` branch in the registry for a entry for the desired type. However, if you've ever installed software that asked if you wanted it to be available for you alone, or for all users of the machine, you've seen a feature that's built in to Windows. When you say "Everyone," its registry entries are generally written to the `HKLM` hive. If you said you alone, those entries generally go to the `HKCU` hive. What `Win32/FakeRean` is doing is putting entries in the `HKCU` hive which take precedence over those in the `HKLM`. For executable files, that can be bad.

Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation for the `IsolatedCommand` key (I've consulted both TechNet and MSDN) but from its name, I'd guess that it controls how a process is created. I *can* tell you that it *is* normal and required in the `HKLM` hive.

Answer (score 4):

I found this when searching about the same question:

http://www.infosecisland.com/blogview/19746-User-Assisted-Compromise-UAC.html

> Under command change the default value to "%1" %* just as it is in
>   HKLM, and add a new String value called '**IsolatedCommand**' with the
>   same value as default. With these settings, very little has changed on
>   the system or its operation.
>
> **> However, if we change the 'IsolatedCommand' String to 'notepad.exe' and attempt to 'Run As Administrator' on that system using any binary
>   guess what happens? Notepad! (as Admin). w00t.**

Answer (score 0):

The `IsolatedCommand` value under `HKLM\Software\Classes\exefile\shell\RUNAS\command\` was used to provide the command that's executed when you select `Run as Administrator` on Windows 10 up to build 17025.

On an unpatched machine, UAC could be circumvented by creating the `IsolatedCommand` entry in HKCU but with different value data, such as `cmd.exe` and then running `sdclt.exe /kickoffelev`. When this exploit was patched after build 17025, the `IsolatedCommand` value remained, but `Run as Administrator` then used the value from the `(Default)` key.

The leftover `IsolatedCommand` appears to no longer serve any purpose.

The `IsolatedCommand` value under `HKLM\Software\Classes\exefile\shell\OPEN\command\` does not appear to have ever served any purpose.